# Window not closing after handling back button

Tags: appcelerator

When I press the back button on the window, then it is not getting closed. If I remove the back button handle, then it is getting closed. Below is the code snippet.

```
$.myWindow.addEventListener("android:back", function() {
 // perform some action
});
```

Can someone please let me know as to why it is not closing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close the window manually if you handle the back button. For example the code should be:

```
$.myWindow.addEventListener("android:back", function() {
 // perform some action
 $.myWindow.close();
});
```

This should resolve the issue.

Comment: Refer to the answer provided by Prashant, which is more detailed and updated when moving to the updated SDK version.

Answer (score 1):

Above answer is incomplete in few terms.

**1. android:back event has been deprecated since Ti SDK 3.0.0.GA**

Use new event ***[androidback](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-event-androidback)*** till Ti SDK **5.5.1.GA**. This is exactly same but it will not be removed in future versions & **android:back** will be removed.

---

**2. *[androidback](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-event-androidback)* also has been changed since Ti SDK 6.0.0.GA.**

From 6.0.0.GA, using **androidback** simply closes the window automatically & executes further code. Simply means, it doesn't over-ride the behaviour of back button press. To over-ride back button behaviour, you must use **[Ti.UI.Window onBack property](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-property-onBack)**

Stick to latest behaviours & changes & you won't need to change your code after future updates.